# What is the part in the sentence that has been omitted?

Tags: grammar

> Remember it all, every insult, every tear. Tattoo it on the inside of your mind. In life, knowledge of poisons is essential. I've told you, nobody becomes an artist unless they **have to**.

—By Janet Fitch

What are the texts that has been omitted?

Comment: The non-elided sentence would be, "I've told you, nobody becomes an artist unless they have to [become an artist]."  "become an artist" is omitted the second time because it would be repetitious.

Comment: Why do you suppose that some text has been omitted?

Comment: @JamesK for the oddness of last part.

Comment: In what way is it odd to you?

Comment: @JamesK semantic oddness.

Comment: "I won't do it unless I have to" is perfectly normal English.

Comment: @KateBunting I know but I only want to know what(part) the author omitted.

Comment: If you know it's standard English, you know it isn't semantically odd. It's simply an omission of an unnecessary repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the texts that has been omitted?

I believe that some text has been omitted from the paragraph. Is that correct? If so, what text has been left out?

The full sentence without omissions would be:

"I've told you, nobody becomes an artist unless they have to *become an artist*"

"become an artist" is omitted the second time because it would be repetitious. Generally speaking this is a common grammatical construction. For example:

"I won't do it, unless I have to"
means
"I won't do it, unless I have to *do it*."

Perhaps equally confusing is the expression "have to" itself. Both "have" and "to" have multiple definitions.

It might be clearer to temporarily translate this as "must":

"nobody becomes an artist unless they must become an artist"
"nobody becomes an artist unless they must"

Answer (score 1):

The semantic oddness is due to the author expressing a surprising idea.  You may disagree with the author.

The author claims that becoming an artist is not a choice.

Every artist has been compelled to become an artist.

Nobody becomes an artist unless they have to *become an artist*.

This may or may not be true. It is possible to express falsehoods in grammatically correct English. It is possible to say (for example) "All lawyers are honest", which is semantically odd, but grammatically correct.